# Why does something taste less sweet after eating something else that is sweet?

Tags: physiology, taste

Why does something taste less sweet after eating something else that is sweet, especially if you don't drink water in-between.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: It happens for food of any taste, not only sweet.

Answer (score -1):

It's a general flaw (IMO bad design) in organic/neural sensor frameworks where inputs tend to be measured relative to previous experience rather than absolute quantitative.

This happens with weights as well. There have been plenty of experiments where people are asked to pick up a heavy weight and then a light weight, then record/estimate the perceived light weight. The next day, they pick up a medium weight and then the same light weight and record the perceived light weight.

The 2nd recording turns out "heavier" because of relative perception.

Suggestion: Computer-mediated nerves designed to measure in absolutes.

Comment: Ugh, I can't disagree with you enough about it being a 'flaw.' Sensory adaptation is almost certainly a feature, not a flaw, and is incredibly well preserved across senses and species.

Comment: Downvote an otherwise fine answer just because you personally disagree with 1 part of it? pathetic... if relative measurements are a feature, perhaps all the measuring instruments you use should use relative measures, everything from weighing scales to CPU Hz configuration and the speedometer in your vehicle. While you're at it, perhaps your electricity and water meters should use relative measurements so you get a ridiculously large bill if your neighbor uses those utilities sparingly. Precision is a virtue, and mechanical precision is something that everyone should aspire to.

Comment: Have you considered that organisms aren't solving the same problems that machines are? I'm not saying relative measurements are good for all things, I am saying they are useful in biology. I'm downvoting because I think your answer is wrong, because it contains no references or explanation the process, and doesn't even contain the word "adaptation" which is the term given to this process in sensory systems.

Comment: "Precision is a virtue, and mechanical precision is something that everyone should aspire to." - Citation needed.

Comment: If your keyboard ever stops typing the precise keys you press, I'm going to laugh. While relative measurements might be good enough for primitive animal life, modern civilized society requires mechanical precision. Example consequences of lack of precision: missing your highway exit and ending up in the wrong town, accidentally putting lower amounts of food/drink in commercial packages and bottles (infuriating customers), and screwing up a recipe because you couldn't measure the ingredients straight.

Comment: When your brain starts receiving non-adapted sensory information, I'm going to laugh. While precise, invariant measures might be good enough for machines and computers, biological organisms need filters that make relevant information salient. Example consequences for not filtering out unnecessary information: not being able to operate a car at all because you are dazzled by the sun and unable to adjust, deafened by the roar of the road that you can't ignore, distracted by being bombarded by dozens of odors from your own body, the air coming in from outside, and the upholstery.

Comment: "When your brain starts receiving non-adapted sensory information" It could be part of what's informally called "human 2.0". Some machine learning frameworks and programs filter or transform data in a way that doesn't use relative measurement yet makes it vastly more useful, such as a database view or a numeric array transform. Filtering out sunlight is handled by the eyes rather than in the brain. The road doesn't roar, and even if it did you would be able to hear everything else by mentally "subtracting" the background noise. You obviously have no clue what you're talking about.